# Hover JQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Вопрос в следующем

при отведении курсора уголок не возвращается в исходное положение, хотя при клике все работает http://www.szsi.com.ua/page/page5/index.html

```
<a id='effect_text'></a>                    
<img src="img/corner.png" id="effect" alt="" />
<img src="img/corner_onclick.png" id="effect_onclick" alt="" />                      
<div id='test_btn'>                     
   <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal1" data-animation="fade"    title="Приобрести">Приобрести</a>                        
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#effect").hover(function() {
        jQuery('#effect_text').fadeOut();
        jQuery('#effect').fadeOut();
        jQuery('#effect_onclick').fadeIn();
        jQuery('#test_btn').show();
        jQuery('#effect').fadeIn();
        });         
        });
</script>
```

http://www.szsi.com.ua/page/page6/index.html - при hover работает угол отгинаеться но невозвращаеться в исходное положение. Подскажите, как сделать чтобы уголок возвращался в исходное положение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#effect").hover(function() {
     действия при наведении
    },function(){
     действия при отведении
    });         
});
```

И все будет работать.

Comment: Блин вот как бывает :)

Comment: Благодарю! http://www.szsi.com.ua/page/page6/index.html  сделал как Вы посоветовали - но при наведении как то криво получилось! Подскажите как исправить

Comment: попробуйте прописать
jQuery('#effect_text').stop(true, true).fadeOut(); только везде так перед show и fadeIn тоже...может поможет.

Answer (score 0):

У задано только одно действие ховера: когда вы навели мышь, задайте когда убрали:

```
$('#effect').hover(function(){

    // тут код когда навели мышку, "отгинается" уголок

}, function(){

   // тут код когда убрали мышку, "загинается" уголок

});
```